# Android Service killed by android V 2.3 (gingerbread)

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a GPS service whose work is to fetch the coordinate into a server. This service suppose to be run 24/7. but it is somehow killed in between.
This is happing only in android v 2.3. On android v2.2 it's running fine.

In this service , i am using "LocationManager" and it's method "requestLocationUpdates" which is creating a loop.This loop is responsible for fetching the coordinates. So my goal is to keep the loop running.

So what to do, to make by service run 24/7.

Comment: can you post the code.. so we can help you better..

Answer (score 2):

```
This server suppose to be run 24/7
```

You **cannot** do that. This is [not possible](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/) in any real sense of the term, as you have discovered. It is also [not a good design choice](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/03/29/code-pollution-background-control/) at all.

If you absolutely need it to be running all the time, you need to 
acquire a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` via `PowerManager`.  This will keep the CPU 
on all the time, and your program running.  Be prepared for a shocking 
decline in battery life.

Instead use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). You can schedule a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) via the AlarmManager thats starts the service at the relevant point in time to do it's work. When done, kill the service again.

Below is a sample code showing how the AlarmManager is used which will launch the intent to start YourService in 5 minutes from now:

```
// get a calendar with the current time
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// add 5 minutes to the calendar object
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);

Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, YourService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 123, intent, 
                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use repeating  Alarm Manager which start your service after a given time period

```
private void setAlarm() {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationUpdateService.class);
        intent.putExtra("locationSendingAlarm", true);
        PendingIntent   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, AppConstants.PENDING_INTENET_LOCATION_SENDING_ALARM_ID, intent,0);
        try {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        int timeForAlarm=5*1000*60; // 5 minutes


        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+timeForAlarm, timeForAlarm,pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Simply you should create notification and update notification wherever you fetch the information in service. If notification is added then os understand some important process is running otherwise whenever os needs memory it automatically kill the process.